# why it doesn't keep the user logged in

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

it doesnt matter if the user is logged in or not it goes to the main page.
anf if i make the login page the home page everytime i restart the app it requires to login again.

i want it to be like once log in then be logged in till you log out

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: await getLandingPage(),
    routes: {
      'upload': (context) => ItemInput(),
      'suzuki': (context) => Suzuki(),
      'others': (context) => Others(),
    },
  ));
}

Future<Widget> getLandingPage() async {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && (!snapshot.data.isAnonymous)) {
        return MainPage();
      }

      return LoginPage();
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: You should add `print(snapshot.data)` or something similar to monitor what data you are actually getting from your stream. The stream might be triggering the build with an initial state before it has had a chance to communicate with firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from Frank's answer, this is how to work around the issue of receiving a `null` on the first `authStateChanges()` event using a `StreamBuilder` widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return _buildWaitingScreen();
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            final firebaseUser = snapshot.data;

            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                //....
            }
            return SignInPage();
          }
      }
    });
```

}

If you don't want to use a switch statement, you can check only `ConnectionState.active`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        //...
      }
      return _buildWaitingScreen();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the app is started, Firebase automatically restores the user's authentication state. This may take a few moments, as it needs to check with the server whether the account is still active.

During this time, the user will not be signed in yet, so `authStateChanges()` fires a `null`. And that's when your code redirects the user to the login page.

You'll want to either wait for a few moments to see if the user state *is* restored, or move/copy your navigation logic to the login page, so that it redirects to the main page once the user authentication state is restored.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> A stream A source of asynchronous data events.
> A Stream provides a way to receive a sequence of events. Each event is either a data event, also called an element of the stream, or an error event, which is a notification that something has failed. When a stream has emitted all its event, a single "done" event will notify the listener that the end has been reached.

Since the `authStateChanges()` returns a `Stream` then you can use the `StreamBuilder` to get the result and display the widgets accordingly.

According to the `StreamBuilder` docs:

> As an example, when interacting with a stream producing the integers 0 through 9, the builder may be called with any ordered sub-sequence of the following snapshots that includes the last one (the one with ConnectionState.done):

- new AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.waiting, null)
- new AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.active, 0)
- new AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.active, 1)
  ...
- new AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.active, 9)
- new AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.done, 9)

Therefore the `builder` of type [`AsyncWidgetBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncWidgetBuilder.html) which is used for asynchronous operation, will call your widgets according to the state of the `Stream`, for example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    return new Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                if (snapshot.hasData)
                  return MainPage();
                else
                  return LoginPage();
              } else
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
            }));
  }
```

You can use the above code in the splash screen, here the `Stream` will be in the waiting state where it will display a loading first, and then when it retrieves the data, if it is either null or if there is a user logged in, it will enter the `active` state and return a widget which satisfies the condition.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncWidgetBuilder.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/builder.html

---

After talking with OP. They are using the following plugin [`google_sign_in`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in), and have an `auth.dart` file with the following code:

```
void signOutGoogle() async {
await googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

What happened in that case, is that the user signed out from Google auth but was still logged in inside Firebase, so to solve this you can add:

```
void signOutGoogle() async {
await googleSignIn.signOut();
await _auth.signOut();
}
```

Comment: Additional discussion is available [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220582/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-abion47).

Comment: i created a splash screen before it and it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Check the edit @MtKhalifa What are you getting now?

Comment: its not getting the _auth

Comment: @MtKhalifa check now

Comment: it redirects to the MainPage() withOut loging in any user